# "Top Tags" appear empty unless I change the sort order at least once

Tags: bug, android-app

I've noticed this issue with the Stack Exchange Android app V1.0.30 (in ICS 4.0.4).

To recreate:

- login to the app
- tap the upper left button and then your username (in my case Kostas)
- in the list of sites that you participate, tap one ">"  (eg. of Super User). You'll see a list of "Top Posts" and "Top Tags"
- tap on one of the "top tags": the screen (that's supposed to list the relevant questions) will appear empty.

If then, you change the sorting from "Relevant" to something else, eg "Active", it will list the relevant questions now. Also, changing from "Active" back to "Relevant" it will also display results now.

I have already tried logout+re-login to the app, and it didn't help.

Comment: Repro'd, and possibly regression on SE app v1.0.83: now changing "Relevant" to "Active" or other still won't display any results.